# How to enable the mouse cursor when only usb mouse plugged in?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3b+, mouse, kiosk

I have configured kiosk in raspberry pi with touch screen.

And

When I am using the USB mouse then cursor is not showing.

I have followed

https://medium.com/stories-from-upstatement/how-to-build-a-web-kiosk-with-a-raspberry-pi-some-cables-and-a-tv-3dc2724acaa1

I am able to hide mouse cursor using

sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils unclutter

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

xserver-command=X -nocursor

but I want to enable the mouse cursor when I plug the USB mouse.

...

Thanks

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [fork](https://github.com/nowrep/unclutter-xfixes) of `unclutter` which can be instructed to hide the cursor on a touch event. When called with a `-touch` argument, it hides the cursor instantly on a touch input, and displays it again on a mouse move.

Alternatively, you can write a `udev` rule and execute your own script which hides the cursor (using `unclutter` or otherwise, e.g. `xinput -cursor /transparent/cursor/file`)
when a mouse is plugged in. A USB mouse can be detected by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237364/106927) rule for instance.